# Why doesnt the binding of a property work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

This is my first question so be careful :)
i'm trying to do a binding of the property (a) in the xaml, the foreground color works(so the ref of the datagrid cell is right), but the background not and i'm trying to understand why, if i try to debug my property the program doesnt enter in it....

```
(a)=
    public int CellGiorno1
    {
        get
        {
            int a = myfunctionexample(day, Username, month, year);
            return a;
            //return 0-1-2
        }
    }
```

(the column of the datagrid where i want to color the background if the number returned is 1)
DataGridTextColumn Header="2"  x:Name="HeaderGG1" Binding={Binding Desc_GG1}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyleGiorno}"/>

```
 (the style with the trigger that color the foreground but not the background)
    <Style x:Key="CellStyleGiorno" TargetType="DataGridCell">      
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CellGiorno1}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem here is your get and set methods. Take a look at this structure:

```
class Name
{
    private string _mynam = "";

    public string mynam
    {
        set
        {
            _mynam = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _mynam;
        }
    }
}
```

You don't have the set method and you set the method in the get method.

Comment: i added the set method but it doesnt work yet, now i'm triyng the mikeT solution, but i cant access to  day, Username, month, year because now i'm in another class....

Answer (score 0):

the property need to have a notification of change structure attached to it to enable binding

this is usually done with INotifyPropertyChanged or DependencyProperty

eg

```
public class myClass :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void ChangeCell()
    {
        PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CellGiorno1")
    }
    public int CellGiorno1
    {
        get
        {
            int a = myfunctionexample(day, Username, month, year);
            return a;
            //return 0-1-2
        }
    }
}
```

so in this case calling ChangeCell would notify all bindings connected to CellGiorno1 that they need to get the value of CellGiorno1 because its changed

Comment: i'm working in this software house by 1 month, i've seen theese INotifyPropertyChanged or DependencyProperty but i thinked those are for update something of the interface...but this may be the answer, now i look careful about this! thank you! i'll answer if it was the problem

Comment: you might want to read this http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/ it covers all the basics of binding

Comment: I read a lot of things of that site hahahaha very usefu....I have a base of it, i've done some function yet, like color with trigger, use multitrigger, but trigger a function it's my problem now....

Comment: "the property need to have a notification of change structure attached to it"
How can i do it?
In this software house's program there is an other binding like that i created, but that call the property, and my not, but i dont find any INotifyPropertyChanged or DependencyProperty that refeer to it

Comment: but also take note of what you are binding and what to, in your code you are binding the value of CellGiorno1 to the dependency property of DataTrigger called "Binding" with out knowing more about your code i can't say this is correct but with out the notify of change hook up the binding will never get the value of CellGiorno1 because it never knows its changed

Comment: i think it is correct but in creating the class for the notify i cant access to day, Username, month, year for my function....how can i correct this?

Comment: the normal way you would do this with MVVM, would be you have your raw data in one class then over the top you would have an editor class, all edits to the data have to pass through the editor so it can then trigger the notify events while passing the changes to the data. otherwise you will have to manually trigger the change notification some other way such as event triggers on controls, but with out knowing how your project works we can't be more specific

Comment: I'm so stupid, it was perfect but it was in the wrong file.cs, i had hours and hoursOfMonth and now it works perfectly! Sorry mikeT to have you come crazy for this question o.o'', thank to you i go re-reading manual of wpf and i find the method for debugging xaml (ctrl+alt+o) and i understood that it tryed to find my method in the other file.cs